# Server keeps timing out

Tags: php, timeout

I have been trying to extend the timeout session of my server, but it keeps timing out at 30 secs. There is an action that I need to perform that takes longer than that and Im not able to solve this.

I added the set_time_limit and max_execution_time to my php.ini file and uploaded it to the root of my site.

```
set_time_limit = 4500
max_execution_time = 3600
```

But it doesn't seem to be taking affect, the server keeps timing out at 30 seconds.

I want to set my server time session to 10 minutes. I will lower it, I just need to perform an action. I would really like some help on this. I've be battling this for some days now and can't figure it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Script Times out after 45 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700196/php-script-times-out-after-45-seconds)

Comment: @Yar: Thanks for the feedback. I read the post and comments and I didn't see where it mentioned duplicate scripts causing the time out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I added the set_time_limit and max_execution_time to my php.ini file and uploaded it to the root of my site.

That won't do: You either need to edit the central php.ini file (the location of which you can find out through `phpinfo()`), or set the time limit inside the code using [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) - if PHP is configured to accept individual overrides of the limit.

Comment: @Pekka: I edited my php5.ini file and tried using the set_time_limit, but it wasn't recognized. I then tried including in the header.php of my site, but it still took no effect.

Comment: I checked php5.ini and session.gc_maxlifetime is set to 1440, but its obviously not being applied.

Comment: Yes, I even went in my file manage and view the php.ini file and it had the value that I set

Comment: @gdinari did you restart the server?

Comment: Im on a shared godaddy server, but I did end all processes. It still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You say you've added those directives to your `php.ini` file, uploaded to the root of your site... But is it really this file that's used ?

You can check which `.ini` file(s) is/are read, by calling the `phpinfo()` function from one of your scripts.

When you've found which `php.ini` file is used, you'll have to modify that file ; and, then, you'll probably have to restart Apache, so the modification is taken into account.

As a sidenote : [**`set_time_limit`**][1] is a PHP function, and not a directive that should be used in `php.ini`.

Of the two lines your posted, only [**`max_execution_time`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) should be in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Thanks, I ran the phpinfo() and found my php.ini file and the max_execution_time is set to the time that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Check your phpinfo() to make sure your php.ini is recognized. You may have to reconfigure your server to accept the php.ini.

Comment: Yes its being recognized: Loaded Configuration File:  ...../html/php5.ini. In the php5.ini file I only have max_execution_time = 3600.