# Premature end of script headers: index.php, mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 61 seconds

Tags: php, apache, timeout, mod-fcgid

I wrote a simple crawling script (in php) at localhost (with 4 variations). All of them worked fine at localhost. But when I made move them to shared hosting, two of them worked others gave internal server error. I looked at error_log and I saw these line:

```
[Wed Jan 23 22:01:02 2013] [warn] [client ***] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 61 seconds
[Wed Jan 23 22:01:02 2013] [error] [client ***] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

I searched but I couldn't find any useful result. What is related to these errors? Any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you can access Linux server please edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf` file with vim.
Change `FcgidIOTimeout 45` to `FcgidIOTimeout 600`.
Restart Apache.
Then Fast CGI timeout will be solved.

Comment: This is the answer to life, universe, weird timeouts! It should be the accepted one.

Comment: @enrey hilaariousss :D

Comment: Would become crazy if this answer was not on stack ! Thanks

Comment: 600 seconds is 10 minutes. If you've a script that's taking this long it'll probably timeout elsewhere too (particularly the user themselves).

Comment: Crazy question for you: what if the config defined both *FcgidMaxRequestLen* and *FcgidBusyTimeout*, but not * FcgidIOTimeout*? Is there a default value if it is not defined?

Comment: Also, FcgidBusyTimeout 1234 ## Should Match PHP: max_execution_time

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on a MediaTemple Grid instance with a Drupal7 install; turns out it was being caused by FastCGI; switching to normal / stable CGI seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: my site on Mediatemple too and that also fixed it

Answer (score 2):

If you're using virtual hosts (in my case i've ispconfig) you need to do changes in virtual host config files. These files are under `/etc/httpd/conf/sites-available` for each virtual host. Just edit your desired config file, locate `IPCCommTimeout` and set current value to a higher number. You may need to do this change for both variables in same config file in case you have regular and SSL sites.

Answer (score 0):

> read data timeout in 61 seconds

They timed out. It's likely your execution time is set to 60 seconds. So at 61 seconds, the process was killed and therefore had a *premature end*.

You can adjust your timeout (not recommended) or run the script through another source (recommended).

Comment: I'd downvote, the answer isn't useful at all and it doesn't say what timeout timeouted. My execution time is at 150 seconds and it still times out at 31.

Comment: The question focused on *what* caused the error not *how to* fix. To your question, and downvote, considering the message was thrown by `mod_fcgid` you should adjust the FastCGI timeout. I'd start there as [**trante**'s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15931470/164998) explains more about *how*.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially your scripts are running too long for the server configuration. mod_fcgid is waiting for php to respond, and its set to give up after 61 seconds. Since this shared hosting, you may not be allowed to change it.

This is not something that should be run via browser/web server anyway. Write it as a console script.

Answer (score 0):

mod_cfgid introduces other time limits besides PHP's `max_execution_time` while executing php scripts. Whichever comes first "wins".

As far as I can see, there are numerous time limit configuration items that mod_cfgid considers, and I'm not the expert to tell which one does which, but at least in our case adding the following line

```
IPCCommTimeout  9999
```

in the `fcgid.conf` solved our unexpected timeout problems.

Answer (score -1):

If any problem involve with mod_fcgid like below:
_mod_fcgid: read data timeout in XX seconds
_mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for

Please fix these issues with priority:

```
_Increasing the memory limit of php (default 128M, up to 256, 384, ... then restart apache anh check it again)
_Increasing the time out of FCGI, but not need if above is ok
```

Answer (score -1):

Increase the `max_execution_time` value, i.e.:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); # 5 minutes
...
```