# mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds

Tags: php, apache

I am getting 2 errors as mentioned below.

**[Fri Jan 09 04:10:23 2015] [warn] [client 188.165.15.22] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds
[Fri Jan 09 04:10:23 2015] [error] [client 188.165.15.22] Premature end of script headers: index.php**

I checked this [Premature end of script headers: index.php, mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 61 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488567/premature-end-of-script-headers-index-php-mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-61-s) also. But I do not have any file like /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf to edit.

Does anybody have any idea?

I don't think that there might be any issue with php script as it as been working fine from past 1 year. Now all of sudden it has stopped working.

My Apache version is 2.2.22 and PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13

Content of fcgid.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c> 
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi 
   FcgidConnectTimeout 20 
   FcgidIOTimeout 2000 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Which version of Apache are you on and on which platform do you run it?

Comment: @HansZ. I have edited my question with apache and platform information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Premature end of script headers: index.php, mod\_fcgid: read data timeout in 61 seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488567/premature-end-of-script-headers-index-php-mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-61-s)

Answer (score 3):

You can increase the timeout as indicated in the other post:

```
FcgidIOTimeout 600
```

But since you are on Ubuntu, you'll find the relevant configuration file here:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf
```

Comment: Yeah I found the file and I edited it by adding "FcgidIOTimeout 600" but still it is not working. I tried it to give "FcgidIOTimeout 2000" also but not working. I have restarted the apache server also.

Comment: The content of fcgid.conf now is <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  AddHandler    fcgid-script .fcgi
  FcgidConnectTimeout 20
  FcgidIOTimeout 2000
</IfModule>

Comment: if the error is still `read data timeout in 31 seconds ` then it doesn't look like `FcgidIOTimeout 2000` was picked up; can you grep all Apache config files and see if you override it somewhere else: `grep -r "FcgidIOTimeout" /etc/apache2/`

Comment: I did grep but it did not give me any result.

Comment: Not even `mod_fcgid.conf`, the file that you just modified?? In that case you have a typo in either one of those.

Comment: These 2 results I am getting            /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf:  FcgidIOTimeout 600
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf:  FcgidIOTimeout 600

Comment: Try restart not reload and if that does not work I'm out of options.

Comment: check you individual site conf too eg: /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain.com.au.conf

Answer (score 2):

For me it was 41 seconds and it was coming from the `httpd.conf` file of the site

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/website.com.conf
<VirtualHost ipv4:80 [ipv6]:80>
  IPCCommTimeout 600 #increased from 41
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `FcgidCmdOptions`, see answer to this question - [mod_fcgid read timeout from pipe, end of script output before headers, multiple versions of PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180713/mod-fcgid-read-timeout-from-pipe-end-of-script-output-before-headers-multiple) . In short - global options are ignored for the program specified in `FcgidCmdOptions`, so all timeouts have to be configured directly in this instruction.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @BhargavRao, I've updated the response.

Comment: You're welcome. I've removed my comment and upvoted your answer. Best of luck and take care the next time you post an answer