# mod_fcgid read timeout from pipe, end of script output before headers, multiple versions of PHP

Tags: php, apache, mod-fastcgi

I've set up several version of PHP under Apache on Windows using mod_fcgid. The configuration is like this:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "c:/php/tmp"
FcgidInitialEnv TMP "c:/php/tmp"
FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
FcgidIOTimeout 600
FcgidConnectTimeout 600
FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 900 
FcgidMaxProcesses 10
FcgidMaxRequestLen 80131072
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000
```

And then a specific fcgi handler in each vhost directive:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "e:/hosts/example"
    ServerName example.local
    # location of php.ini
    FcgidCmdOptions c:/php/php5.5.12/php-cgi.exe InitialEnv PHPRC="c:/php/php5.5.12/"
    FcgidWrapper "c:/php/php5.5.12/php-cgi.exe" .php
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:81>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "e:/hosts/example"
    ServerName example.local
    # location of php.ini
    FcgidCmdOptions c:/php/php7.0.12/php-cgi.exe InitialEnv PHPRC="c:/php/php5.5.12/"
    FcgidWrapper "c:/php/php7.0.12/php-cgi.exe" .php
</Virtualhost>
```

This way http://example.local/ works with PHP 5.5, but http://example.local:81/ serves the same code but with PHP 7.0. Very convenient for testing multiple versions of PHP on the same system.

But I keep getting fcgi timeouts after about 40-60 seconds, which prevents me from using xdebug effectively.

I have checked number of similar questions on SO, most of which correctly suggest to set higher value of `FcgidIOTimeout` option, but for unknown reason this has absolutely no effect on my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering my own question hoping this will save someone hours of fighting with this problem.

Having spent quite a lot of time on this, I've figured our that the culprit was in using **`FcgidCmdOptions`** in vhost configuration. If it's defined, **global fcgid options are simply ignored**! So, instead of setting `FcgidIOTimeout` I had to set `IOTimeout` option in `FcgidCmdOptions`.

The final configuration is the following:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "e:/hosts/example"
    ServerName example.local
    FcgidCmdOptions c:php/php5.5.12/php-cgi.exe \
            InitialEnv PHPRC="c:php/php5.5.12/" \
            InitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000 \
            IOTimeout 3600 \
            ConnectTimeout 3600 \
            MaxProcessLifeTime 7200 \
            IdleTimeout 3600 \
            MaxRequestsPerProcess 900
    FcgidWrapper "c:php/php5.5.12/php-cgi.exe" .php
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:81>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "e:/hosts/example"
    ServerName example.local
    FcgidCmdOptions c:php/php7.0.12/php7-cgi.exe\
            InitialEnv PHPRC="c:php/php7.0.12/" \
            InitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=1000 \
            IOTimeout 3600 \
            ConnectTimeout 3600 \
            MaxProcessLifeTime 7200 \
            IdleTimeout 3600 \
            MaxRequestsPerProcess 900
    FcgidWrapper "c:php/php7.0.12/php7-cgi.exe" .php
</Virtualhost>
```