# Converting XML to CSV using PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv

I need to convert an XML file to CSV.

I have a script but I am unsure of how to use it to my needs.

Here is the script

```
$filexml='141.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) {
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
$f = fopen('141.csv', 'w');
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($item),',','"');
}
fclose($f);
}
```

The file is called 141.xml and here is some of the code in the XML which I need to convert.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">



<channel>
<item>
<title><![CDATA[//title name]]></title>
<link><![CDATA[https://www.someurl.co.uk]]></link>
<description><![CDATA[<p><span>Demo Description</span></p>]]></description>
<g:id><![CDATA[4796]]></g:id>
<g:condition><![CDATA[new]]></g:condition>
<g:price><![CDATA[0.89 GBP]]></g:price>
<g:availability><![CDATA[in stock]]></g:availability>
<g:image_link><![CDATA[https://image-location.png]]></g:image_link>
<g:service><![CDATA[Free Shipping]]></g:service>
<g:price><![CDATA[0 GBP]]></g:price>
</item>
```

I am running the script from SSH using:

php /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.co.uk/httpdocs/xml/convert.php

If you can help me, it would be really appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors ? is the 141.csv file empty after you executed the sctipt ? I am unsure of what your issue(s) are, it seems as if you are already doing it right, unless you got errors.

Comment: *I have a script but I am unsure of how to use it to my needs.* please don't take me wrong, but wouldn't it be best use of your time googling for the parts you don't understand of your script and **then**, in face of errors and unexpected behavior you bring it to SO? Because if you can't even understand how 'your' script works, it'd be pointless if we give you any answer to any problem you might have with it.

Comment: Unless you want us to *explain* it to you.

Comment: There are no errors and no output csv file. Do I need to specify a location? Does the script look right? :/

Comment: The script does exactly and simply what you might want it to do, it opens a XML, creates a new .csv file inside the root directory **which is expected to have writing permissions to www-data**, iterates over the xml object and parses it into comma separated values, then closes it. If it isn't working but no errors are being displayed, you have read/write permissions or path issues with your file directory. Insert an `else` clause after `if` echoing something like "error fetching file"

Comment: If you are getting no errors, then you may want to check your 141.xml file path. check in the script whether it is going in the "if" condition or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider passing XML data into an array `$values` and exporting array by row to csv.

Specifically, using the `xpath()` function for the XML extraction, iterate through each `<item>` and extract all its children's values (`/*`). By the way, I add headers in the CSV file.

```
$filexml='141.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml))  {

   $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
   $i = 1;           // Position counter
   $values = [];     // PHP array

   // Writing column headers
   $columns = array('title', 'link', 'description', 'id', 'condition',
                    'price', 'availability', 'image_link', 'service', 'price');

   $fs = fopen('141.csv', 'w');
   fputcsv($fs, $columns);      
   fclose($fs);

   // Iterate through each <item> node
   $node = $xml->xpath('//item');

   foreach ($node as $n) {           

       // Iterate through each child of <item> node
       $child = $xml->xpath('//item['.$i.']/*');      

       foreach ($child as $value) {
          $values[] = $value;         
       }

       // Write to CSV files (appending to column headers)
       $fs = fopen('141.csv', 'a');
       fputcsv($fs, $values);      
       fclose($fs);  

       $values = [];    // Clean out array for next <item> (i.e., row)
       $i++;            // Move to next <item> (i.e., node position)
   }
}
```

Comment: You have my respect, this is exactly what I wanted in regards to the output file. thank you very much :) I have a slight problem now though as when it is creating the file it throws up 500 Internal error and the output file differs in size every time. I have increased the memory limit to 512 but this didnt help?

Comment: Check your PHP error log file for specifics as 500 is a generic server error message. As for changing file size each time, see if XML file changes regularly too.

Comment: The website is on shared hosting but I have tried it on one of our servers and had the same problem which gave the error:  mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds

Comment: Try adjusting your [FcgidIOTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488567/premature-end-of-script-headers-index-php-mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-61-s) setting past 45. More useful links with [google search](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=mod_fcgid+php&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=mod_fcgid+read+data+timeout+php).

Comment: apparently my shared hosting doesnt allow such modifications. I am running it on the server now so all is good :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code. And the XML file is having syntax error, the closing tag for rss and channel is missing.

```
$filexml='141.xml';
if (file_exists($filexml)) 
 {
       $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml);
       $f = fopen('141.csv', 'w');
       createCsv($xml, $f);
       fclose($f);
 }
 function createCsv($xml,$f)
 {
       foreach ($xml->children() as $item) 
        {
           $hasChild = (count($item->children()) > 0)?true:false;
           if( ! $hasChild)
           {
              $put_arr = array($item->getName(),$item); 
              fputcsv($f, $put_arr ,',','"');
           }
           else
           {
              createCsv($item, $f);
           }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Hey, Tried the code but nothing is happening. I have read.write permissions on all files and folders and regarding the XML file, I have just not included the bottom part of the file but the closing tags are there.

Comment: What error you are getting..? If you don't have csv file, still the code will create one with the output. To get the actual error, try adding this in the very beginning of the file ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: For some strange reason it wasn't working over SSH but when I tried it on a browser it created it so thank you. the only problem is that the content is in one cell instead of separate cells. do you know how I can fix this?