# Server/websites very slow loading

Tags: php, mysql, server, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have a server for 5 month now with Debian 7 Wheezy and cpanel virtual/webmin installed. Never had any problems except a week ago.

I did not do any changes on the server. The problem is as follows:
The first time when I checked the websites a week ago i received the DAtabase error 500 connection on every website i visited on the server.

I then checked status of server and MySQL was down. So i put this up and installed all updates in virtualmin and then restarted. All was working fine, until 10 minutes later. The website became very slow.
When I checked error log i got the following:

```
[warn] [client ] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds [] 
[error] [client ] Premature end of script headers: xmlrpc.php
```

I then changed  FcgidConnectTimeout=600 to 9999 for /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cfgid.conf. Again i did a restart and all was working fast again. ten minutes later same issue. Sites are loading very very slow.Sometimes more then a couple of minutes.

I checked error log again and i found the following error:

```
[warn] [client ] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /home/fcgi-bin/
```

Comment: what's your machine config? Do you have swap added? Do you have ssd drives or normal ones?

Comment: this is most probably an issue with your ram getting full..

Comment: It's a Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2130 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 4 cores with 2x1 TB SATA drives, not sure about swap.   There is almost no traffic on the websites so ram hitting max would be strange.

Comment: This might be useful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488567/premature-end-of-script-headers-index-php-mod-fcgid-read-data-timeout-in-61-s